# Count data in form input

Tags: javascript

can i ask ?

```
function sum() {
        var k =1;
        while (k < 100) {
            document.getElementById('qty'+k+'').value;
            document.getElementById('satuan'+k+'').value;
            document.getElementById('harga'+k+'').value = document.getElementById('qty'+k+'').value * document.getElementById('satuan'+k+'').value;  
            document.getElementById('subtotal').value = document.getElementById('harga1').value ;  
        k++;
        } 
    }
```

how to count all data in document.getElementById('harga'+k+'').value and placeing result in document.getElementById('subtotal').value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your codes to

```
function sum() {
document.getElementById('subtotal').value =0;
        var k =1;
        while (k < 100) {
            document.getElementById('qty'+k+'').value;
            document.getElementById('satuan'+k+'').value;
            document.getElementById('harga'+k+'').value = document.getElementById('qty'+k+'').value * document.getElementById('satuan'+k+'').value;  

document.getElementById('subtotal').value = 
parseInt(document.getElementById('subtotal').value)+ parseInt(document.getElementById('harga' +k + '').value) ;          

k++;
        } 
    }
```

Comment: var k =1;
        while (k < 100) {
            document.getElementById('qty'+k+'').value;
            document.getElementById('satuan'+k+'').value;
            document.getElementById('harga'+k+'').value = document.getElementById('qty'+k+'').value * document.getElementById('satuan'+k+'').value;
            var sub = 0;
            var total = parseInt(sub) + parseInt(document.getElementById('harga'+k+'').value);
            document.getElementById('subtotal').value = total; 
        k++;
        }

Comment: i adding value 0 but they dosn't count all data harga. only show the last data. can you help me to count all data harga

Comment: Please try my revised answer.